# Time Value of Money

Tags: statistics, finance

Santana is planning for his pension savings:

- He plans to work for $20$ years and then retire.
- He expects to receive an annuity income of $\$\, 20000$ at the start of each year of his retirement for $30$ years.
- If the interest rate remains unchanged at $3\,\%$, how much should Santana put into his pension account at the start of each working year $?$.

*I tried to use the PV due annuity formula
$$
{A\left(1 + i\right)\left[1 - \left(1 + i\right)^{-n}\right] \over i}
$$
to solve this question but couldn't get the answer. It might be something to do with the $20$ and $30$ years but I don't know what is wrong. The answer is: $\$\,14589$. Please help $!$. Thank you $!$.

Comment: Please see [this article on MathSE protocol](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/33190/how-to-avoid-downvotes-for-beginners-questions/33236#33236).
As onerous as the article may appear to you, it provides a defense mechanism against the MathSE forum being used as a *do my homework* forum.  In particular, please see the **Edit-Tools** section of the article, and the portion of the article that discusses *showing work*.  Homework problems are allowed, as long as the protocol is
observed.

Comment: Re previous comment, please edit your posting, using [MathJax](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation) to very carefully provide all of the requested details.  This includes slow and careful elaboration of all of your work.  Please do not respond with a comment.  The details belong in your posting.

Comment: Personally, if I was attacking this problem, I would set the time of $20$ years in the future as time $T_0$.  Then, I would calculate the expected value of the annuity at $T_0$.  Then I would calculate the expected value of the payments that begin immediately, where again, I am looking at what the expected value will be at $T_0$.

Comment: In a problem like this, it is not a good idea to attempt to blindly use a formula.  Instead, you have to stretch your intuition to understand **the derivation of the formula**.  Then, you use your **stretched intuition** to attack the problem, rather than trying to blindly follow a formula.

Comment: Since interest doesn't change, calculate how much money you would need to start with to receive $\$20000$ a year for thirty years. The balance is zero after thirty years. Call that starting value $B$. Then, starting from zero savings, compute how much you would need to save each year to have a savings of $B$ after twenty years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed it is not a good idea to use a formula for such a question, math from high school may help in understanding it better. Consider the following equations:
After 20-year work, the pension account,
$$
T_{t=20} = \sum_{i=1}^{20}S_{aving}\times(1+r_{ate})^i
$$
For the next 30 years, total saving decreases. At the last year,
$$
T_{t=50} = T_{t=20}\times(1+r_{ate})^{30-1} -\sum_{i=1}^{30}a_{nnuity}\times(1+r_{ate})^{30-i}
$$
We expect $T_{t=50} = 0$. Then solve the equation, we get
$$
\begin{aligned}
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{20}S_{aving}\times(1+r_{ate})^i\right)\times(1+r_{ate})^{30-1} &= \sum_{i=1}^{30}a_{nnuity}\times(1+r_{ate})^{30-i}\\
\left(\sum_{i=1}^{20}S_{aving}\times(1+0.03)^i\right)\times(1+0.03)^{30-1} &= \sum_{i=1}^{30}20000\times(1+0.03)^{30-i}\\
27.67648 \times S_{aving}\times 2.35656 &\approx 951508.31412 \\
S_{aving} &\approx 14589
\end{aligned}
$$